# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion

Tags: vb.net, narrowing

I've been having issues regarding this narrowing conversion error

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
>
> 'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'owner' narrows from 'String' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'.
>
> 'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'caption' narrows from 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle' to 'String'.
>
> 'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'buttons' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'.
>
> 'Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons, icon As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'buttons' narrows from 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'.

I did some research and the generic solution for "Overload resolution failed because no accessible '' can be called without a narrowing conversion: " errors is to Specify Option Strict Off according to Microsoft. I tried changing this manually in the Project Properties but it didn't seem to work.

This is the code where the error is occurring:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a value for ESD (rad)", "ESD (rad) Value", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.OK Then
            txtCal_USE_Radio.Focus()
```

I've also checked several other forums where they talk about this error but specifically related to the 'New' function and they don't seem to help.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: The Error tells you what is wrong 2ce.  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel` is for use with the legacy `MsgBox()` and is not the same as `MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel` from the Winforms NameSpace.  Intellisense will help you with these things if you let it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've invoking `Show({string}, {MsgBoxStyle}, {MessageBoxIcon})`, so the last overload in the error message is the closest:

> 'Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String, buttons As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons, icon As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'buttons' narrows from 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'.

That's `Show({String}, {String}, {MessageBoxButtons}, {MessageBoxIcon})` - you're missing a `caption` argument, and instead of `MsgBoxStyle` you should use the `MessageBoxButtons` enum.

Sounds like you have `Option Strict On` - that's <s>good</s> excellent - but it seems you also have `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic`, which is essentially polluting your *IntelliSense* with VB6 back-compatibility stuff, which `MsgBoxStyle` is part of; that enum means to work with the legacy `MsgBox` function, which `MessageBox` is a more .NET-idiomatic replacement for.

Switching off `Option Strict` would be the single worst thing to do - you're passing a bad parameter and the compiler is telling you "I can't convert the supplied type to the expected one"; last thing to do is to make it say "hey don't worry, just implicitly convert all the things and blow up at run-time instead".

*IntelliSense*/autocomplete should be telling you what to do *as you type the arguments into the function call*; re-type the opening parenthese `(` and watch *IntelliSense* highlight the parameters and their respective types as you use the arrow keys to move the caret across the arguments you're supplying.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got this code from another person who had worked on it and it was a mess! There were no comments and they gave me no direction so this has been a great help for me!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your MesssageBox with MsgBox Change MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel to the MessageBox syntax.

```
If MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a value for ESD (rad)", "ESD (rad) Value", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = DialogResult.OK Then
```